# Issue with extending django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a site where you can sign up to be either someone who uses the service(customer) or someone who provides the service(worker). I have created two profiles in models.py to represent each. They are both extremely similar for the most part as of right now. Both forms display properly when you go to them, and if you are signing up as a customer and press submit everything goes smoothly and a new user under will show up in "Customer profiles" at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ . But if you try to sign up as a worker, the following error appears:

```
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no workerprofile.
```

I do not understand this because as you will see in the code below i use `customerprofile` and it works fine, if I use `workerprofile` it crashes.

Views.py:

```
def signup_as_worker(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.workerprofile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.workerprofile.university = form.cleaned_data.get('university')
            user.save()  # explicitly save custom fields not in User model
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)  # login user after signup
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = WorkerSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'core/signup_as_worker.html', {'form': form})

def signup_as_customer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.customerprofile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.customerprofile.university = form.cleaned_data.get('university')
            user.save()  # explicitly save custom fields not in User model
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)  # login user after signup
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CustomerSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'core/signup_as_customer.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class WorkerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #birth_date and university fields need to be declared seperately because they are not apart of User:
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    university = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'birth_date',
                  'university',
                  'password1',
                  'password2', )


class CustomerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #birth_date and university fields need to be declared seperately because they are not apart of User:
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    university = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'birth_date',
                  'university',
                  'password1',
                  'password2', )
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class WorkerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'USER')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_worker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        WorkerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_worker_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.workerprofile.save()




class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'CUSTOMER')
    needLaundryDone = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_worker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CustomerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_worker_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customerprofile.save()
```

I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal handler method names for both models are the same. You are practically redefining the methods therefore only the second set of methods are called. Rename your `CustomerProfile` handlers to `create_customer_profile` and `save_customer_profile`.

Comment: Thank you selcuk I have not yet added customer and worker specific fields, but if they all share 'birth_date' and 'university' is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: @JustinO'Brien If you simply want to reduce the amount of repetition, you can use an [abstract base model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and include all the shared fields there. This will end up with exactly the same database structure but your code will be more compliant with DRY principle.